# What is difference between "static def at" and "static at"

Tags: groovy, geb

I was going through the docs

```
http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.2/api/geb/Page.html
```

and found the `at` closer is defined as `"static def at"` but the same in `Page.groovy` is

```
static at = null
```

and not `static def at =null`

Any difference.

Comment: The `def` isn't required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None at all. Both can be understood as

```
static Object at;
```

Answer (score -1):

You are looking into documentation, where you see how classes/interfaces/traits are defined. It's presented exactly the same way as you would write your classes, etc.

When you use it in Geb you can skip `def` in `static def at = null`, because you are using function/closure that is already defined.

Also: use http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/ instead 0.9.2. Geb is already in 0.12.2! ;)